# Mono Process.Start returning ExitCode 255?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, exit-code

I have a simple C# Mono 2.10 application running on CentOS 5.5 that calls

```
Process.Start("/path/to/myapp/myapp.exe","-someArgs");
```

I am able to get a process ID back and running with

```
mono --trace=N:System.Diagnostics
```

Shows me a stack that seems to indicate that Process.Start returned true:

```
LEAVE: System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process)TRUE:1
LEAVE: System.Diagnostics.Process:Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo,System.Diagnostics.Process)TRUE:1
LEAVE: System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()TRUE:1
LEAVE: (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()TRUE:1
```

Which I assume means the process was spawned without an exception like FileNotFound etc..

However, the process seems to exit immediately and **the exit code I get is 255**. I assume this is a Linux exit code with some obvious meaning but I can't find anything of use on the tubes.

When launching the exact same application directly via

```
mono /path/to/myapp/myapp.exe -someArgs
```

The application launches correctly without any exception and works as expected.

Any clue what I am screwing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the file `/path/to/myapp/myapp.exe` an executable file (`chmod +x /path/to/myapp/myapp.exe`)? Mono 2.10 does check to see if the process it's starting is a managed executable, and if so will implicitly use the currently executing mono to launch the new process, e.g. [Mono's CreateProcess source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/processes.c#L521). `CreateProcess` contains all the details, but among them:

- [The process must be executable](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/processes.c#L641)
- [The process must be a managed binary](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/processes.c#L812)

If `Process.Start` still fails to start your process, then that's a probable mono bug and we'd love to have a bug reported for it. :-)

Comment: ok so you win with the new answer, for the definitive explanation. If I ls -l on my my exe the permissions are this -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: So even after forcing a chmod +x on myexe (which it already was) it still fails to launch my process. So a bug in mono then?

Answer (score 2):

Try launching "mono" as the process, and use "/path/to/myapp/myapp.exe -someArgs" as the command line arguments.  That will cause the Process.Start to behave more like your normal application launch.

Comment: I thought about trying that let. Let me see what happens

Comment: Awesome, that fixed the problem. Makes sense, the "application" I am launching is "mono" not "myapp.exe" thanks

Comment: This should not be necessary, as mono's CreateProcess() explicitly checks for managed executables and implicitly uses the same `mono` to launch them. Is "/path/to/myapp/myapp.exe" executable (`chmod +x`)? See also: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/io-layer/processes.c#L812

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Linux itself doesn't know that it needs to use Mono to run CIL .exe binaries, so it tries to use ld-linux.so as the loader, which for obvious reasons fails.

You need to invoke mono with /path/to/myapp.exe as an arg.

FWIW, an exit code of 255 is just "error".

Comment: I figured 255 was useless, thanks for the info. Reed beat you by a few minutes but both answers are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start process using this overloading of Process.Start:

```
Process.Start("/bin/bash", "-c \"echo 'Hello World!'\"");
```

Don't know why, but it works.